# Multiple logistic regression ggplot with groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

This is just kind of annoying me, so I'm hoping someone has an idea. I'm running a multiple logistic regression where there is one numeric predictor and one categorical predictor. I'd like to make a nice looking ggplot of the logistic regression of the model (without an interaction term, so the curves should just be translations of each other). For example:

```
data("mtcars")

library(ggplot2)

glm(data = mtcars, vs ~ mpg + as.factor(gear))
```

Creates a model. One idea would be

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = vs, color = as.factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(
    method = "glm",
    method.args = list(family = "binomial"),
    se = F
  )
```

but this creates a separate logistic model for each group, which is a different model. The best I've come up with is to use predict() with a response type and then add a geom_line() with y = prediction_value. This looks right-ish, but it's not as smooth as using geom_smooth. I know I could also use predict() on more points to smooth it out, but this seems like there must be a nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I find if you're trying to get ggplot to do something that is non-standard (i.e. an uncommon or unusual transformation), it works out easier and quicker if you just calculate what you want to plot, then plot it using straightforward ggplot syntax.

```r
library(ggplot2)

fit <- glm(vs ~ mpg + factor(gear), data = mtcars, family = binomial)

new_data <- data.frame(gear = factor(rep(3:5, each = 100)),
                       mpg  = rep(seq(10, 35, length.out = 100), 3))

new_data$vs <- predict(fit, newdata = new_data, type = "response")


ggplot(data = mtcars, 
       aes(x = mpg, y = vs, color = as.factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = new_data, size = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I suspect you might be right, but I can't help feeling like the geom_lines there look quite a bit sloppier than the smooth function that geom_smooth makes. :(

Comment: @Matt they are produced in the same way (both use `grid::linesGrob` to draw the line), so that shouldn't be the case. Try increasing the "smoothness" by increasing the number of predicted points in the `new_data` data frame, or adjusting the `size` parameter of the line.

Comment: oh thanks! I didn't realize that they both used that - I'll just keep increasing the number of predicted points. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like that maybe?

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = vs)) +
  geom_point( aes(color = as.factor(gear))) +
  geom_smooth(
    method = "glm",
    method.args = list(family = "binomial"),
    se = F
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I still want to have three logistic curves in the plot - one for each level of gear, but to ensure that they fit the model, e.g. that they're only translations of each other and have the same slope.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that has worked for me is this:

1. change the categorical values into 0, and 1 unless you have not yet done so.
2. run your ggplot command as above but change geom_smooth to:

```r
stat_smooth(method="glm", se=TRUE,
             method.args = list(family=binomial), aes(group = [name of your groups]))
```

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, this still models each group separately (e.g. equivalent to including an interaction term, so the slopes of each group are not required to be equal)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).